# Query or filter based on ANY column in the source sheet matching a given cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'd like a formula to return all the matching values from column A if ANY of columns B-AZ equal the query value. Said differently:

=query(DATA!A:Z, "select A Where 'DATA!B:AZ' = C2").

Formulas I cobbled together, but don't work:

```
=query('Inv by shelf'!A:AZ,"Select A WHERE '"&C1&"' = '"&TEXTJOIN("|",1,'Inv by shelf'!$B:$AZ)&"'",1)
```

```
=filter('Inv by shelf'!A2:A,'Inv by shelf'!B:AZ = C1)
```

TIA!

Comment: Share your sample workbook here so that we can check it.

Comment: I've added a link. Thanks for looking

Comment: Please provide edit permission.

Comment: Sorry, I just changed it

Comment: check my answer and let know your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `FILTER()` formula with `MMULT()`.

```
=FILTER('Inv by shelf'!A2:A,MMULT(ArrayFormula(--('Inv by shelf'!B2:Z=C1&"")),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS('Inv by shelf'!B2:Z2),1,1,0)))
```

Functions references.

[MMULT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094292?hl=en)
[SEQUENCE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244?hl=en)
[FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)

See you workbook sheet `harun24hr`.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but I thought this would be trivial. How can I adapt this formula to retrieve the qty from the relevant column?

So your formula returned what value in Column A matches C1. Now how can I retrieve the number value under each of these values?

Comment: Just change filter range `A2:A` to `A2:Z`.